# digitalocean: couldn't connect to host

Tags: curl, digital-ocean

I've created a fresh droplet on digitalocean, deployed my docker container, tested the endpoint via `curl ip:dockerPort` from my local computer and everything went fine.

Later on i've connected to another test machine via ssh and tried to connect to digital ocean via `curl ip:dockerPort` as well but got an `couldn't connect to host` error. I've connected from my test machine to digitalocean droplets in the past. Do i have to wait for the DNS even if i'm using `curl ip:port`?

EDIT: pinging the server from the test machine works well:
`8 packets transmitted, 8 packets received, 0.0% packet loss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred due to slow DNS updates of the test network. I could successfully connect to the freshly created instance after i've added googles DNS server `8.8.8.8` to the settings.
The DNS got finally refreshed after a 48 hours and i was able to remove googles dns again.